# SharePoint Time Sheet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I want to create a time sheet for the company where user can enter hourly basis task for everyday for a week so we can track weekly / monthly how many hours user has worked on particular task.

Can you please share some idea / example which help me to create this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the out-of-the-box SharePoint Project Site template. It tracks assignments, tasks, team effort and can be customized further to your requirements - 
[Understanding SharePoint 2013 Project Site Templates](http://blog.fpweb.net/understanding-sharepoint-2013-project-site-template/)